# How to remove this hinge to remove box cover

Tags: electrical, hinges

I need to take the door off of this to get access to the bolts to remove it and access the inside:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [installation instructions](https://www.legrand.us/~/media/products/resources/wiremold-products/infloor-ducts/service-fittings/recessed/floorport-recessed-covers/1008150r2pdf.ashx) ([found here](https://www.legrand.us/wiremold/infloor-ducts/service-fittings/floorport-recessed-covers/fpctc-cutout-cover-assembly.aspx#.VnBraL-nSao)), there is a cover in the center that is removed, then two pins pull out, allowing the box cover to be removed.  Once removed, there are 4 bolts in the corners of the box holding the face plate on.

[image]